# pgfplots: Using two horizontal colorbars within one plot

Tags: pgfplots

For my work I'm going to need a graphic with two seperate colorbars. According to the pgfplots manual there is the lowlevel key `/pgfplots/colorbar/draw/.code={⟨... ⟩}` (chapter 4.9.12, page 233). I've managed to implement a second colorbar based on this key. But the problem is that the second colorbar seems to ignore the `colorbar horizontal` key and therefore it's rendered vertical (see attached minimal working example).

Does someone had the same problem or has any idea to fix this issue?

**Example**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    colorbar style={
      at={(0.75,-0.8)},
      anchor=center,
      width=3cm
    },
    colorbar/draw/.append code={
      \begin{axis}[
        colormap/blackwhite,
        colorbar horizontal,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        every colorbar/.append style={
          at={(0.25,-0.8)},
          anchor=center,
          width=3cm
        },
        every colorbar,
        colorbar shift,
        colorbar=false,
      ]
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colorbar addplot}
      \end{axis}
    }]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the `every colorbar/.append style` fails to work as expected. However, since it is set in a context of a color bar, you can directly set the options. This works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    colorbar style={
      at={(0.75,-0.8)},
      anchor=center,
      width=3cm
    },
    colorbar/draw/.append code={
      \begin{axis}[
        colormap/blackwhite,
        colorbar horizontal,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        every colorbar,
          at={(0.25,-0.8)},
          anchor=center,
          width=3cm,
        colorbar shift,
        colorbar=false,
      ]
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colorbar addplot}
      \end{axis}
    }]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I didn't thought on setting it directly into the axis environment but since the colorbar is actually a axis itself it seems like a straight forward solution. Maybe one should incorporate it into the manual to use the keys directly rather than modifying the style with `.append`.